# Use AngularJS on website and still get indexed by search engines

Tags: javascript, angularjs, search-engine

I want to rebuild an old website made on plain HTML and add some extra functionality with AngulaJS. But since I plan to use ng-views to render templates on my main layout, is it possible to make search engines still find the templates of these subpages?

Answer (score 1):

In a general sense, this is not an angular problem - its the same problem with any single page site that uses javascript to generate your html.

The general solution would be to detect when it is a crawler accessing your page instead of a person (usually by using the query agent string), and then use server side logic to render pages that are suitable for the crawler to process.

Here is one article that discusses this problem:

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/10/how-to-optimize-single-page-sites-for-search-engines/

but google (or searching this site) for "google seo single page app" will give you lots of other ideas.